# Copy paste of price regarding latest date in a range in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I can not get any further. Maybe someone can help me here. I have almost 3,000 dates ahead, for which I need the net prices from the most recent date. For this I have added an example in the appendix.

Table 1 shows the different numbers of the components with their respective names. For each number, the net price relative to the most recent date and also the most recent date should be searched for on table 2 and added to the corresponding line in table 1.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoBDT.png)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdM3.png)

Unfortunately, I have the problem that the component numbers appear several times on Table 2 and I can not check the individual areas to the latest date with my VBA knowledge.

Best regards,

Bamane

Comment: did my formula work?

Comment: @learnAsWeGo Which Formula you mean? 
Also I need to use a vba code cause there are many people who works on this sheet who cant change formula.

Comment: I deleted because I realized it was not working as I had intended

Comment: Okay, thank you for your support. :)

Answer (score 0):

I try the formula above and functioning good but if two components fall on same latest delivery date, second component will take price on first component. What's my mistake?

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you for helping me. Is this code also working without typing functions into the cells? It should be only VBA.

Comment: Must type function into the cells. Function similiar to our created formula.

Comment: I see, it would be nice just to use VBA codes. Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: lookup latest date's price]

Can try function also to lookup latest date'price